# Adding image to the segment controller

Tags: ios7

Prior to iOS 7 it was easy to add colored image to the segment controller, but now if I add image to it, only the image is visible with the default Tint color and not the actual color.

Does any one have idea about this, if so kindly help me out.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Fix it with: imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal

```
UIImage *segmentImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Example"];

if ([UIImage instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)]) {
     segmentImage = [segmentImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
}

[self.control insertSegmentWithImage:segmentImage atIndex:i animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
UIImage *segmentSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Off.png"]
                            resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 6, 6, 6)];
UIImage *segmentUnselected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"On.png"]
                              resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 6, 6, 6)];
UIImage *segmentSelectedUnselected =
[UIImage imageNamed:@"dividerOn.png"];
UIImage *segUnselectedSelected =
[UIImage imageNamed:@"dividerOff.png"];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected
                                           forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected
                                           forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected
                                           forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segUnselectedSelected
                             forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal // | UIControlStateHighlighted
                               rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segUnselectedSelected
                             forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateHighlighted
                               rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentSelectedUnselected
                             forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                               rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal //| UIControlStateHighlighted)
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentSelectedUnselected
                             forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                               rightSegmentState:UIControlStateHighlighted
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
UIColor *textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            font, @"NSFontAttributeName",
                            textColor, @"NSForegroundColorAttributeName",
                            nil];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes
                                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score -1):

simply change the segmentController tintcolor to UIColor clearColor, use style controlstyleborder

```
SegmentControl.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
[SegmentControl setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```